# Javascript no se puede leerla propiedad 'value' - nulo

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero pasar el valor de un boton a un input, seguramente es un error con el DOM pero no sé.
Pruebo con compiladores y corre bien el codigo pero al momento de probarlo con navegadores no corre da el siguiente error: 
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at prueba.js:1*

Estoy aprendiendo.  Gracias de antemano.
   **Javascript:**

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    boton.onclick = function(e){
      resultado.value +=  this.value;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="boton" value="7">7</button>

<input type="text"  id="resultado">
```

Comment: Tu código funciona correctamente si lo pones todo junto. El único detalle a saber es si quieres concatenar el valor en cada clic, remplazar o realizar otra acción.

Comment: Perdón pero no entendí, ya lo hice pero no da en navegadores

Comment: Ya edite tu pregunta y funciona el snipet al momento de ejecutarlo, si estás creando de forma dinamica el input, te recomiendo utilizar `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    boton.onclick = function(e){
      resultado.value +=  this.value;
 } })` de esta forma esperamos a que cargue todo el contenido y después procede a efectuar las funciones.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes hacer uso de jquery

```js
$(function() {
     $("#button1").click(function() {
      let getval = $(this).attr('value');
      $("#input1").val(getval);
     })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<button id="button1" value="hola"></button>
```

Lo que hace la funcion es que al dar click en el boton toma su atributo value y depues se lo pone al input.

Comment: Me parece que no es adecuado el uso de una librería (framework o lo que sea) para algo tan sencillo.